# Problems Editing XML in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

Working on a program that edits XML using isolated storage (MUST always be in Isolated storage). However, i'm recieving an exeption when I run my code:

A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll

Edit 1: Also recieving: An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary (Occasionally)

Here's the code:

```
    var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    using (Stream stream = storage.OpenFile("voicecmd.xml", FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        XDocument str1 = XDocument.Load(stream);
        var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.0");
        str1.Root.Element(ns + "CommandSet").Element(ns + "CommandPrefix").Value = texb.Text;
        str1.Save(stream, SaveOptions.None);
        await VoiceCommandService.InstallCommandSetsFromFileAsync(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/voicecmd.xml"));
```

Comment: what line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that those exceptions are only outermost ones. And this would be inner reason for them:

You are opening file with FileMode.Truncate and then trying to read from stream with XDocument.Load()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx :
"Specifies that the operating system should open an existing file. When the file is opened, it should be truncated so that its size is zero bytes. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. Attempts to read from a file opened with FileMode.Truncate cause an ArgumentException exception."

Also because there is windows-phone-8 tag and there is lingering possibility of windows store being involved:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(v=vs.110).aspx
"Isolated storage is not available for Windows Store apps. Instead, use the application data classes in the Windows.Storage namespaces included in the Windows Runtime API to store local data and files. For more information, see Application data in the Windows Dev Center."